Post-target in Makefile
I have a Makefile with several targets, and I want to automatically run a target named collect-data-point after any target is called. I'm trying to figure out how to add this post-target execution without manually adding it to hundreds of targets.
Running collect-data-point as a dependency would be straightforward, but  thats's not what I need. I need to capture values that are only generated after the target runs. Therefore, I need the collect-data-point target to execute only after the main target finishes.
Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this?
Basiclly:
# Wait for jobs and pods to be ready in a given namespace
wait-resources:
    @. $(SUPPORT_SCRIPT); TIMEOUT=$(TIMEOUT) \
        APP_NAME=$(APP_NAME) \
        waitForResources $(NAMESPACE) $(HAS_OPERATOR_RESOURCES) $(FAIL_IF_JOB_MISSING)

# Monitor all resources in the specified namespace
monitor-resources:
    @echo "Monitoring resources: '$(NAMESPACE_RESOURCES)' in namespace '$(NAMESPACE)'"
    @watch kubectl get $(NAMESPACE_RESOURCES) -n $(NAMESPACE)

# Retrieve resources from the specified namespace
fetch-resources:
    @echo "Fetching resources: $(NAMESPACE_RESOURCES) from namespace '$(NAMESPACE)'"
    @kubectl get $(NAMESPACE_RESOURCES) -n $(NAMESPACE)

# Detailed description of resources in a namespace filtered by an app label
describe-app-resources:
    @. $(SUPPORT_SCRIPT); HELM_REPO=$(HELM_REPO) describeResources $(NAMESPACE) $(APP_NAME)

# Display logs for pods in a namespace with a specific app label
logs-app-pods:
    @. $(SUPPORT_SCRIPT); HELM_REPO=$(HELM_REPO) getPodLogs $(NAMESPACE) $(APP_NAME)

# List pods in a specific namespace
list-namespace-pods:
    kubectl get pods -n $(NAMESPACE)

# List container images for a specific app within a namespace
list-pod-images:
    kubectl get pods -l app=${APP_NAME} -n $(NAMESPACE) -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}:{' '}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{end}{'\n'}{end}{'\n'}"

# Export the current KUBECONFIG as base64
export-kubeconfig:
    @KUBE_CONFIG_BASE64=`kubectl config view --flatten | base64`; \
    echo "Encoded KUBE_CONFIG_BASE64: $$(echo $${KUBE_CONFIG_BASE64} | cut -c 1-40)..."; \
    echo "Added to: RulesConfig.mak"; \
    echo -e "\n\n# Encoded from: kubectl config view --flatten\nKUBE_CONFIG_BASE64 = $${KUBE_CONFIG_BASE64}" >> RulesConfig.mak

These are some of the target I will run.
Then I have this metrics target, that I want to run everytime one of those targets runs.
Most of these variables are gitlab global variables.
define METRICS_TARGET_BODY
{"CI_PIPELINE_ID":"$(CI_PIPELINE_ID)","CI_JOB_ID":"$(CI_JOB_ID)","MAKE_TARGET":"$(MAKECMDGOALS)","MAKE_VERSION":"$(MAKE_VERSION)","CI_PROJECT_ID":"$(CI_PROJECT_ID)","CI_PROJECT_PATH":"$(CI_PROJECT_PATH)","STATUS":"$$?"}
endef
export METRICS_TARGET_BODY
    
collect-data-point:
    @curl -s -v -X POST $(DATA_ENDPOINT)/point \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d "$$(echo '$(DATA_POINT_BODY)' | sed 's/\"STATE\":\"$$?\"/\"STATE\":\"'$$?'\"/')" \
    > /dev/null 2>&1 || true &

When I run make fetch-resources, fetch-resources should run and when it finishes collect-data-point should run.
If I run make fetch-resources monitor-resources, it should run fetch-resources folowed by collect-data-point target, then monitor-resources folowed by collect-data-point target.

Adding it as a prerequisite is not right: that would have it run BEFORE any of the targets are run, not after.  I don't understand your second paragraph; you haven't provided a specific enough question.  Do you want the metrics target to run just one time after all the other targets are complete?  E.g., what if you run make target1 target2 target3?  Do you want it to run if the the other targets fail, or not?

I edited the paragraph, maybe it makes more sense now. I want it to run always after a target runs, successfully or not.
In that example it should run 3 times, one for each target

Make will never run a target more than once. I can instead recommend generating all your targets using foreach and eval, and using that to add common code to them.

I still have no idea what you mean by $(STATUS) in the second paragraph: there's no variable STATUS visible or mentioned anywhere else in your question.  Nevertheless it seems there's enough to answer the question now.

"to check if the ran target was successful or not" - The protocol is that if the command executed for the target exits with 0, it was successful and Make will continue, otherwise the dependencies can't be built and compilation will terminate. You don't have to check anything manually.

I removed the $(STATUS). I meant that I need some values that are only generated in those targets that will run. Metrics is supposed to send those values as json to an endpoint

What do you mean with "values that are generated in a target"? What kind of "value"? A number? A file? Something else? Please edit your question and show exactly what each targetXXX produces, how it is supposed to be passed to the  metrics rule and what the metrics rule is supposed to do with it.

As HolyBlackCat says, it's impossible to get a single invocation of make to build the same target (e.g., run the recipe for the same target) more than one time.  Make always builds a given target only after all its prerequisites have been updated, and it always assumes that the recipe will update the target, so there's never a need to run it again.
If you want the code to always run even on failure, you have limited options.  One way is to create a user function and call that:
METRICS = $1; err=$$?; echo "sending vars to endpoint"; exit $$err

target1:
        @$(call METRICS,echo "1")
target2:
        @$(call METRICS,echo "2")
  ...

Note that this will fail if the command to be run contains a , character.
Another option is to use recursive make; this would be straightforward if and only if the names of your targets are really well-formed such as you describe above (e.g., target{1..999}).  If they are random it will be harder.  This is the downside of creating simple examples, that may not accurately reflect your real situation.

Unfortunately they are all different and random. But thanks for the insights

An idea for a work around:
Place a function into .bashrc
function mymake()
{ 
  make "$@" metrics
}


This would not work for concurrent builds, as the metrics target would likely be started before any of the other targets are finished (unless you had dependencies in the makefile, at which point this approach would be moot).

It also won't work for multiple targets building at the same time: mymake target1 target2 target3 since it will only build metrics one time, rather than after each target.  And of course it assumes that all users of the makefile are willing and able to add this to their shell setup and run mymake instead of make.
